# Read the file error C_language

Tags: c, file, fopen

i am trying to create file and write some data on it, but when i run the following code program runs to error: Error    1   error C2664: 'errno_t fopen_s(FILE **,const char *,const char *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'FILE *' to 'FILE **'

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *myFile;


int main()
{
    int age;
    age = 24;
    fopen_s(myFile,"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\DATA.EMP", "w");
    if (myFile == 0){
        printf("Error opening the file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(myFile, "I am %d years old \n", age);
    fclose(myFile);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

what might be the reason?

Comment: The compiler error tells you pretty clearly. `fopen_s` expects an arg 1 of type `FILE **` and you are giving it `FILE *`. Try with first arg `&myFile`.

Comment: I figure it out, i already declared  as FILE **myFile;  but it gives me another error  Degub Assertion failed!
program:....al studio 2013\projects\file_pointer1\debug\file_pointer1.exe File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\stdio\fopen.c Line: 159 
Expression: (pfile!=NULL)                     
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE **myFile;


int main()
{
 int age;
 age = 24;
 fopen_s(myFile,"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\DATA.EMP", "w");
 if (myFile == 0){
  printf("Error opening the file\n");
  exit(1);

 }
 fprintf(*myFile, "I am %d years old \n", age);
 fclose(*myFile);

 getchar();
 return 0;
}

Comment: No don't do that! That will compile but will fail at runtime as you have found out. The fopen_s call will derefence the first argument. You have to give it a pointer to allocated memory. By making your variable `FILE **` you are passing an invalid pointer to fopen_s. Do what has been suggested: declare as `FILE *` and pass `&myFile` to `fopen_s`. And you probably want to brush up on pointers before you proceed further.

Comment: it is time to read the manual (as you should do for every system function call).  As some say, the devil is in the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx

```
errno_t fopen_s( 
   FILE** pFile,
   const char *filename,
   const char *mode 
);
```

Thus, your code should be:

```
fopen_s(&myFile,"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\DATA.EMP", "w");
```

N.B. the &myFile.

And check your return value.

Comment: Thanks, i missed that, i should reference to the address of variable where the data will be stored